# Joining two tables to count and list and sort

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, teradata

Table1: Keywords

```
ItemID  KWtype   KWvalue

1       Brand     Nike
2       Brand     Nike
1       Type      Soccer
4       Brand     adidas
```

Table2: Items

```
ItemID  SiteID  CategoryID  ItemName

1        0         10         Shoe1
2        0         10         Shoe2
3        2         55         Shoe3
4        1         11         Shoe4
```

I have these two tables (who are of course a lot bigger)

How to I proceed to know which are the 10 most occurring brands in Site = 0 and Category = 10? 
I want to list the top 10 (top 10 occurring brands) in one column and in the other column I want to count how many times they appear

Thanks

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: what have you written so far?

Comment: It's Teradata, I'm a bloody beginner in SQL so i have2 written down much...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should really adjust your data model. It would work a lot more efficiently like this and is easier to understand

Table: Brands

```
ID  ItemID  BrandName

 1       1  Nike
 2       2  Nike
 3       4  adidas
```

Table: Types

```
ID  ItemID  TypeName

 1       1  Soccer
```

Table: Items

```
ID  SiteID  CategoryID  ItemName

 1       0          10  Shoe1
 2       0          10  Shoe2
 3       2          55  Shoe3
 4       1          11  Shoe4
```

Build foreign keys to link the ItemID in the brands and types tables to the ID in the items table.

Then you can run a query like this

```
SELECT brandname as Brand, count(brand.id) as Qty
FROM brands
LEFT JOIN items ON items.id = brand.itemid
WHERE siteID = 0 AND categoryID = 10
GROUP BY brandname
ORDER BY qty DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Hi, I joined a company, there is nothing I can change in the data model :)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the count:

```
SELECT k.KWvalue as Brand, count(*) as Qty
 FROM items as i
 JOIN keywords as k
   ON i.itemid = k.itemid
WHERE k. KWtype = Brand
  AND i.siteID = 0
  AND i.categoryID = 10
GROUP BY k.KWvalue
```

Returning the top 10 counts depends in your DBMS.

Darren H already wrote it for mysql, simply add

```
ORDER BY qty DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Teradata:

```
SELECT k.KWvalue as Brand, count(*) as Qty
 FROM items as i
 JOIN keywords as k
   ON i.itemid = k.itemid
WHERE k. KWtype = Brand
  AND i.siteID = 0
  AND i.categoryID = 10
GROUP BY k.KWvalue
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Qty DESC) <= 10
```

Oracle (and most other DBMSes):

```
SELECT Brand, Qty
FROM
 (
   SELECT k.KWvalue AS Brand, COUNT(*) AS Qty, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Qty DESC) AS rnk
    FROM items AS i
    JOIN keywords AS k
      ON i.itemid = k.itemid
   WHERE k. KWtype = Brand
     AND i.siteID = 0
     AND i.categoryID = 10
   GROUP BY k.KWvalue
 ) dt 
WHERE rnk <= 10
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this when back in the office :)